# Get sell to specific countries field from API in woocommerce

Tags: reactjs, woocommerce, next.js

I am building a checkout page using Next.js and I want to show the countries I have chosen in WooCommerce that the user can choose from. The WooCommerce field is called 'Sell to specific countries' in the backend and on the frontend of a standard Wordpress/WooCommerce site the dropdown is called 'billing country'.

I have checked the WooCommerce API docs but I don't see an endpoint for getting this list of countries. Does it exist?

Comment: Checkout `$countries_obj = new WC_Countries();`

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Jo but that isn't an API endpoint where I can use React to fetch the countries

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. This seems to work `    $woo_countries = new WC_Countries();
    $countries = $woo_countries->get_allowed_countries();`

Comment: I've posted a full answer with two possible ways to access the allowed countries in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the countries in you JS files, there are two ways to deal with this by not using an official WC API.

**Solution 1 (The JS solution):**

First you need to pass the countries to your JS file somehow. You can do this with the localization feature of WordPress. For this, go to your file where you add your script. You normally do this with this function:

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', 'path/to/my-script.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
```

Now you can use the localize function to find the script and pass your countries:

```
$countries = new WC_Countries();

wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'my_script', [
    'countries' => $countries->get_allowed_countries()
]);
```

In your JS you can now access this data with `console.log( my_script.countries )` for example.

**Solution 2 (Own endpoint solution):**

With solution 2, you can create your own endpoint in WordPress. If I were you I would first read this stuff here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

With the knowledge you can create your own endpoint now. I don't want to describe everything because it's a lot and I think you can do this!

There are 3 parts to handle:

1. Registration of custom endpoint
2. Authentication
3. Callback

First you need to register a custom endpoint which looks like this and create a callback function:

```
register_rest_route( 'user8463989/v1', 'countries', [
        [
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'            => 'get_allowed_countries',
            'permission_callback' => '', // <- you can do a permission check here like if the user is allowed and has correct caps
        ]
    ]
);
function get_allowed_countries(): WP_REST_Response {
    $countries = new WC_Countries();
    return new WP_REST_Response( [
        'data'    => $countries->get_allowed_countries()
    ], 200 );
}
```

Now you can call your endpoint with a basic JS http request by calling this URL:

https://your-page.com/user8463989/v1/countries

If everything is correct and the authentication works, you will get your list of countries.

Solution 1 is tested and works - solution 2 needs some work from you too because of the authentication stuff (in case you need some). Otherwise everyone can access your allowed countries. If thats okay for you, go for it.